# Logstash timer metrics not working

Tags: timer, logstash, metrics, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I am using `logstash 2.3.4`

I receive lignes which are basically apache logs with a small score at the end ( calculated trough machine learning, thanks to Spark ). Here's what a line look like :

```
hackazon.lc:80 192.168.100.133 - - [28/Jul/2016:11:07:46 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10442 "http://192.168.100.123/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36" pred:0.0859964494393
```

As you can see the first part is an standard apache log and the end is `pred:0.0859964494393`.

The logs are processed by ELK for visualization, and I also want to have some metrics on the score called `pred`. Therefore I used the `timer` option from `metrics`. Here is my logstash config file :

```
input {
    file {
         path => '/home/spark/LogStash/*'
         start_position => "beginning"
    }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG} pred:%{NUMBER:pred_score}"}
    }

    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
         drop { }
    }

    mutate {
    convert => {"pred_score" => "float"}
    }

    geoip {

        source => "clientip"
    }

    metrics {
        timer => ["pred_score" , "%{duration}"]
    }

}

output {
#    elasticsearch { }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
#    riemann{
#    map_fields => true
#    }
}
```

I expected to get output with the mean, ax etc... of the pred score. However I have only some 0, except for the count and rates.

Here is one of the output from timer :

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-07-28T09:11:39.522Z",
       "message" => "thamine-OptiPlex-755",
    "pred_score" => {
           "count" => 10,
         "rate_1m" => 0.5533102865966679,
         "rate_5m" => 1.2937302900528778,
        "rate_15m" => 1.490591754983121,
             "min" => 0.0,
             "max" => 0.0,
          "stddev" => 0.0,
            "mean" => 0.0,
              "p1" => 0.0,
              "p5" => 0.0,
             "p10" => 0.0,
             "p90" => 0.0,
             "p95" => 0.0,
             "p99" => 0.0,
            "p100" => 0.0
    }
}
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank's in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Your grok pattern looks good but in your logstash script `%{duration}` is unknown. Neither `COMBINEDAPACHELOG` nor your pattern has the `duration` variable.

Change your timer configuration to:

```
timer => ["pred_score" , "%{pred_score}"]
```

as `pred_score` is the variable in your pattern